# How to output multiple arrays in same feed

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, feed

I have two queries resulting in differing sets. I want to output both results in the same feed-div, using PHP and MySQL, sorted by the publishing date. The feed should deliver both news and blog posts.

I was thinking I would get the two result sets out from the db, then store them in an array, and from here I need some inspiration as to how I would extra an element from each array compare their timestamp and insert the newest value into the feed before the other one. Perhaps into a third array first, and then do a simple loop from that.

Am I overdoing this? Is there a simpler way?

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I can't bridge the gap yet, so I havn't tried anything I think should work.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't be able to provide the specific code, but, perhaps an inner join query (joining the  two blog and news tables) sorted by the mysql date descending property would be sufficient.

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work. A JOIN query seems to deliver the result set with each row holding both columns for news and blog posts. I need something that sorts them in different rows, so the loop can just output them as any other.

Answer (score 1):

Combine the separate feeds into a single array using timestamps as keys, sort by key, then loop as you normally would.

Comment: In the SQL query or between that and the loop?